# Is there an UDF implementation in Spark R available

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks

I am new with Spark in R
Is it implemented in Spark R the UDF functions please? Does it work with Arrow encoder?

SparlklyR UDF is not optimized using Arrow on Databricks or otherwise

We thought  we must come up with a Spark R UDF instead, running on same dataframe with Arrow encoder installed like library(arrow)).
Databricks only Support Spark R, Sparkly R is vendor specific (R Studio) and not supported and optimized.
Any advice here for this scenario ? Below my code, but R UDF can be anything possible for a dataframe we read from path

---

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(arrow)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
sdf <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "dbfs:/FileStore/tmp/udf_test_fake")

identity <- function(rdf){
  worker_log(paste0("Processing ", digest::digest(rdf), " partition with ", nrow(rdf), " rows"))
  return(rdf)
}

result <- spark_apply(sdf, identity)
print(sdf_nrow(result))
```

Comment: Have you checked Databricks documentation? https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/gallery/DistributedRUserDefinedFunctions.html https://www.databricks.com/blog/2018/08/15/100x-faster-bridge-between-spark-and-r-with-user-defined-functions-on-databricks.html https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/r/sparkr-gapply

Comment: Thank you Alex. Isn't that link related to machine learning, as mentioned from get go in "In the examples below we will train a model ", where the ask is for a sample and simple UDF function only? May you pass any other example pls?